# UIButton setTitle moves image

Tags: ios, uibutton

The weirdest thing. I have a `UIButton` with an image and a title.

The only code that touches the button is this:

```
if ([[MomentCreationShared sharedMySingleton].owner._id isEqualToString:[UserDataManager getCurrentUserID]])
    {
        [cell.createMomentButton setTitle:@"Create a new Moment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.createMomentButton setTitle:@"Create a moment of your own" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Although `cell.createMomentButton` frame `imageEdgeInsets`,`titleEdgeInsets` and `contentEdgeInsets` are the same (checked with breakpoints)
The image gets offset-ted a bit and I cant' seem to figure out why:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mention imageEdgeInsets are the same but what about contentEdgeInsets property. Might be worth checking for consistency.

Comment: true... But they are the same as well with value of (0,0,0,0). So is titleEdgeInsets

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. One last suggestion is (if you haven't already) try changing the title text to some short string like @"Hi" to observe what the image does.

Comment: Actually the original is "Create a new Moment" which is shorter, I thought it has something to do with that. In the screenshot the text amount is roughly the same...